# Spring: Servlet 3.1 + SockJS = Async support must be enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, asynchronous

I´ve switched my Spring MVC configuration from XML to JavaConfig and integrated Websocket with SockJS.

My issue is, that the application with websocket and the configuration works fine on "localhost" (tomcat 8.0.36). But when i upload the war package to my server (tomcat 8.0.32) then the websocket connection fails with the following error code:

> Failed to open session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container] with root cause
>    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container

I´am not sure what the reason for this situation.

See below my Initializer:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer   {

  @Override
  protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
  }


protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { MyAppConfiguration.class, MyAppSecurityConfiguration.class };
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter,  
                          new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain").s};
}
```

}

In MyAppConfiguration.class async was enabled "@EnableAsync":

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling 
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

In the pom.xml i load the javax.servlet-api

```
        <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I checked the spring docs but didn´t find any reason, why the application doesn´t work on the server, but on localhost :-(

On my localhost i access the tomcat directly and on the server by AJP connector. Maybe must something enabled within the AJP connector to support async request?
The ajp connector and apache webserver was temporary disabled and i accessed my project direct with the tomcat url (:8080) .. but the same error :-/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue ;-)

After upgrading my apache tomcat vom version from 8.0.32 to 8.5.4, all works now. I ´am able to communicate with websockets and use ajp .. so, please don´t use the 8.0.32 and choose instead >= 8.5.4.